# How to log/ inspect a $resource in a $scope variable in AngularJS controller?

Tags: angularjs

In a controller, when I get a resource from a service

```
$scope.myVariable = MyObject.get($scope.id);
```

then `myVariable` is not defined as MyObject since it will be resolved later. Is there a way to inspect the variable *in the controller* (not in the service), for example for debugging or logging? Basically I am looking for something like

```
console.log("myVariable now has property "+ $scope.myVariable.myProperty);
```

Comment: I don't know if this will work with resource, but you might want to try adding this to your controller: `$watch('myVariable', function(value) { console.log(...) })`.  You may need to add a third parameter to $watch -- `true` -- if you want "deep checking"/[object equality checking](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$watch), rather than just reference checking

Answer (score 2):

From AngularJS Doc to [$resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource), you can read that:

> It is important to realize that invoking a **$resource** object method
>   immediately returns an **empty reference**.
>   Once the data is returned from the server the existing reference is
>   populated with the actual data. This is a useful trick since usually
>   the resource is assigned to a model which is then rendered by the
>   view. Having an empty object results in no rendering, once the data
>   arrives from the server then the object is populated with the data and
>   the view automatically re-renders itself showing the new data. **This
>   means that in most case one never has to write a callback function for
>   the action methods**.

**But**, if you need to print the value of `$scope.myVariable` once it gets populated, you will have to define a callback function:

```
$scope.myVariable = MyObject.get($scope.id, function(myVar){
   // From now, myVar == $scope.myVariable
   console.log("myVariable now has property "+ myVar.myProperty);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this may be very useful. But if I want to see the variable in the controller? `$scope.myVariable = MyObject.get($scope.id); $scope.myVariable.myProperty='modified Value'; console.log("myVariable now has property "+???)`

Comment: Hum, you should post your `controller` and `service` code then, because I don't get precisely what you mean :)

Comment: In this case (logging), your solution works perfectly. I was just looking for a more general solution. To me it seems unnatural to have a variable but not its value. Sure, the asynchronous call has advantages, but if my following code depends on a property of the result, it gets "inconvenient", resp. I have to follow another approach. If I wait for say five variables to be loaded I would need to define five functions for that, which IMO pollutes the code.